# How can I find the right index in a chunk, knowing only the chunk index?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have a chunk like this:

```
c  i   i
 +---+---+
0| 0 | 1 |
 +---+---+
1| 2 | 3 |
 +---+---+
2| 4 | 5 |
 +---+---+
3| 6 | 7 |
 +---+---+
```

How can I find the right index for say chunk (c) 3 place 0?

I have an array like this:

```
let array = [
    0,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
]
```

Then I part it into chunks and loop through:

```
let chunks = [
    [
        0,
        1
    ],
    [
        1,
        2
    ],
    [
        3,
        4
    ]
]
```

I have tried like this:

```
chunks.forEach((data, chunk) {
    const key1 = array[chunk + 0]; // works fine on first row
    const key2 = array[chunk + 1]; // works fine on first row
});
```

But it produces an invalid result:

```
+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | // correct
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | // invalid, should be: 2, 3
+---+---+
| 2 | 3 | // invalid, should be: 3, 4
+---+---+
| 3 | 4 | // invalid, should be: 5, 6
+---+---+
```

Comment: can you rephrase the question? It is not clear.

Comment: @Addis I have posted a solution I found to the question

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be rather simple (`chunckIndex*2+index`):

```
chunks.forEach((data, chunkIndex) {
    const key1 = array[chunkIndex * 2 + 0];
    const key2 = array[chunkIndex * 2 + 1];
});
```